# Wrapping a listing containing formatted spans

Tags: html, css, indentation, rouge

I have an HTML `<listing>` tag which contains may `<span>` tags with `color` CSS styling, generated by Ruby's Rouge syntax highlighting engine. A `<listing>` is used because the markup contains whitespace which must be rendered.

I'm having trouble getting the text to wrap correctly though. I want to apply `word-wrap: normal; overflow-wrap: break-word;` wrapping to the entire `<listing>`, but it seems to just ignore these preferences, and  the text spills over the sides.

```html
<listing style="width: 200px; height: 200px; word-wrap: normal; overflow-wrap: break-word; background-color: #eee;">
<span style="color: #444"># This is a comment, but it's too long.</span>
<span style="color: blue">public</span> <span style="color: blue">class</span> <span style="color: black">Empty {
    <span style="color: #444"># This is indented using markup.</span>
    <span style="color: red">A.Long.Chain.Of.Accessors.And.Other.Calls()</span>
<span style="color: black">}</span>
</listing>
```

This is how the HTML appears on my browser (Firefox):

[image]

This is the result I'm after:

[image]

I've tried applying the formatting rules to the `span` tags too, but this didn't make any difference.

How should I fix the wrapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listing` tag has by default `white-space:pre`...Try to change it to `pre-wrap`

> ***Note***
>
> [*`<listing>` tag is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/listing)

```css
listing {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<listing style="width: 200px; height: 200px; word-wrap: normal; overflow-wrap: break-word; background-color: #eee;">
  <span style="color: #444"># This is a comment, but it's too long.</span>
  <span style="color: blue">public</span> <span style="color: blue">class</span> <span style="color: black">Empty {
    <span style="color: #444"># This is indented using markup.</span>
  <span style="color: red">A.Long.Chain.Of.Accessors.And.Other.Calls()</span>
  <span style="color: black">}</span>
</listing>
```

Comment: Fantastic, this worked great. Thanks for your speedy answer. Will accept in 8 mins